OLS estimate of a panel model
I am new to panel data models and I have a question. I have generated data in Stata using to the following generating process:
set seed 345398
  drawnorm alpha_i, n(200)
  expand 5
  drawnorm nu_it e_it, n(1000)
  g x_it=nu_it+alpha_i
  drop nu_it
  g y_it=3+alpha_i+2*x_it+e_it

I realize that the OLS estimate of $y_{it}$ on $x_{it}$ will be biased due to a correlation between $x_{it}$ and $\alpha_{i}$. However, I am wondering if the estimate will still be biased when regressing $y_{it}$ on $x_{it}$ and $\alpha_{i}$? Furthermore, will the standard obtained from this regression be correct?
Thank you in advance!
